# MongoDB-Express::ENOTDIR: not a directory,...gssapi.js/package.json

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using `mongodb` in my `express-js` project. I am trying to run the server in `vs code` but it is throwing errors with the npm packages. It works fine with `Webstorm` and from `command-line`.

```
Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, stat '/home/user/Workspace/Project1/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/auth/gssapi.js/package.json'
    at Error (native)
    at fs.existsSync (fs.js:219:13)
    at find_package_json ('/home/user/Workspace/Project1/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/require_optional/index.js:13:9)
    at require_optional ('/home/user/Workspace/Project1/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/require_optional/index.js:37:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> ('/home/user/Workspace/Project1/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/auth/gssapi.js:27:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
```

I have tried installing packages many times and updated `npm` itself but could not fix it. Can someone please advise how to fix this? Thanks.
This is my `package.json` file.

```
{
  "name": "Project 1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Project 1 apis",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "license": "BSD-2-Clause",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "connect-multiparty": "^2.0.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "csvtojson": "^1.1.7",
    "express": "~4.14.0",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.31",
    "mongoose": "^4.11.6",
    "mongoose-double": "0.0.1",
    "morgan": "^1.8.2",
    "static-favicon": "^2.0.0-alpha",
    "uniqid": "^4.1.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: at the time of `npm install` ?

Comment: No, but when running the server in vs code. It works fine with Webstorm and from command line.

Comment: select the correct terminal from the drop down, and run it again

Comment: Did you ever solve this, by trying a another terminal?

Comment: @DauleDK Yes, I got around it, I cleaned up the package files and reinstalled. It didn't work at first so I reinstalled latest versions of npm and node. It seemed like the best thing to do.

Comment: and what launch configuration did you end with using?

Comment: { "version": "0.2.0", "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/www"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: @DauleDK Its the default one, I never had to make a change here.

Comment: Ok - I keep getting the same error, so created a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I solved it by just removing sources from disk, cloned repo to another folder, install all packages and then it starts working.

Hope that will help you.